# I'm not getting the correct sum for this geometric progression word problem.

Tags: geometric-progressions

This is another question my teacher asked to do as homework. I've been getting the sum for this word problem.
Here's the word problem:
**A man on a diet loses 1.5% of his weight during each week.**
(a) If he initially weighs 150kg, write down his body weight at the end of each of the first 5 weeks.
Here's my working out:
[image: My working ou for (a)]
(b) How much does he lose in total during that time?
This is the part of the question I've been trying and have been getting the wrong sum. Here's my working out:
[image: Working out for (b)]
The sum for alternate (b) is approximately 727.84kg and it clearly doesn't make sense. I checked the back of the text book where my teacher got this question from and the answer is 10kg. I did the question over and over again and kept coming up with 727.84kg. How do I get 10kg?

Comment: Are you sure it says 10 kg not 11kg? Also for (a) you need to have the weight at each of the first 5 weeks.

Comment: Yes, the back of the book agrees with the answer for alternate (a).

Comment: I have tried (b) and got 11kg. Are you sure 10kg is correct?

Comment: I actually got 10.9175kg, and I can't see how it is 11kg!

Comment: 10kg is what the back of the text book said but I think it's 10 point something. The text book usually gives answers that are rounded to a whole number.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how it is 10kg, I do know that it is 11kg.

Comment: The answer on the text book must be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you are wondering, you can get 139.0824754 by doing:
$$150\times(1-\frac{1.5}{100})^5$$
The 1- bit gets you 0.985, and you can use a this method, a similar method to compound interest, to find the answer of 139.08..... then to get 10.9175
Hope this helped!

Comment: So $$(1-\frac{1.5}{100})$$ is the common ratio right?

Comment: If that the person loses 1.5% each week, he will finish the 1st week with 147.75kg. Then, you have to do another 1.5%, but of 147.75. My method simply does 1.5% of each value quickly, just like the compound interest method, which you probably should have done.

Answer (score 2):

You have just added all the terms of the G.P. which is not asked in the question actually the question asks about the decrease in weight i.e. the last term 5<sup>th</sup> term in your case.

As per my calculations the fifth term is 139.0824754.
If you subtract it from the first term you get 11.

## 150 - 139.0824754 = 10.91752465 or 11

Method 2(Direct Method):

let X be the weight lost by the person then:

## X =  a(1-(r)<sup>n</sup>)

## = 150(1-(0.985)<sup>5</sup>)

## =150(1-0.927216502365625)

## =150(0.072783497634375)

## =10.91752464515625

Comment: A friend of mine at school did something similar.